# Java to batch file

Tags: java, batch-file

Can any body help me in knowing how to pass a parameter from a Java program to a Batch file which is also used in the same java program.

The following stub indicates the piece of code where I run the batch file

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
rt.exec("C:/test.bat");
```

I need to know if I could pass some parameters to test.bat which is used in the above snippet.

Comment: Could you tell us why you need to run a batch program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use a string array as the arg to Runtime.getRuntime().exec().  see the [JavaDoc](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec(java.lang.String[]))

```
 public Process exec(String[] cmdarray) throws IOException
```

Comment: Wrong answer. envp - array of strings, each element of which has environment variable settings in the format name=value, or null if the subprocess should inherit the environment of the current process.

Comment: You linked the right overload, but wrote the wrong one. envp is a array of environment variables, not an array of parameters. The right one is exec(String[] cmdarray) (just a single String[]), as given by ammoQ.

Comment: you are right.  the link was the original, but i too quick to copy the signature out of source!  sorry @Harish, if i led you astray. it has been corrected.

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
String[] cmd = { "C:/test.bat", "param1", "param2" }
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
rt.exec(cmd);
```

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure you just stick it on the end the string, same as if you were to run it on a command line:

```
rt.exec("C:/test.bat "+someparm+" "+anotherparm);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you insert the parameters into the `exec()` call?

```
 rt.exec("C:/test.bat <param 1>...");
```

I think the syntax to get at the parameters in the bat file is:

```
%1 for first param    
%2 for second...
```